# Print out a union select

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
$query = mysql_query("  ( SELECT naam 
                          FROM users_social 
                          WHERE user_id = 1 )
                        UNION 
                        ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(datetime)) as days 
                          FROM users_social_invoer 
                          WHERE user_id = 1 )"
                    );
```

Now I can echo the first part of the query (the 'naam') with the following echo:

```
echo mysql_fetch_row($row_query[0]);
```

However echo'ing $row_query[1] does NOT print out the 2nd part of the query (the union select) as I would like to. How do I actually print out that part of the query? thanks

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: It looks like you want to join, not union.

Comment: Looks like you are UNIONing 2 different data types. I thought that should not be allowed

Comment: _If it works_ It will return 2 rows, one for each select. So you need 2 fetches, each one will provide data in `$row_query[0]`

Comment: The query works because when I run it in phpmyadmin it gives me 2 rows.. but I just don't understand how to echo the 2nd row in php (so the 2nd fetch). Because $row_query[0] gives me the 'naam' so why doesnt $row_query[1] give me the 2nd value

Comment: @Kevin you have to loop for each row

Comment: Why doesn't $row_query[1] work? Because you fetched one ROW. Then, you got COLUMN 0 from that row. You then tried to get COLUMN 1 from the row, when it only has 1 columns (index 0). You need to fetch the next ROW to get another row. Overall, you are doing so much wrong that the rest of your project is certain to fail. You are using mysql_ functions. You are confusing rows and columns. You are using union when you want join. You really need to step back and try to do it correctly instead of just hacking away at it and hoping it will magically work.

Comment: `mysql_*`, in this day and age?

Comment: @kainaw You are right, but in this case looks like OP doesn't know much about query. So instead of  blame him for trying to `"hack"` just guide him on what he should check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `JOIN` instead of `UNION`

```
SELECT us.naam, count(DISTINCT DATE(usi.datetime)) as days
FROM users_social as us
JOIN users_social_invoer as usi
  ON us.user_id = usi.user_id
WHERE us.user_id = 1    
GROUP BY us.naam
```

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. I actually want to order by the value of count(DISTINCT DATE(usi.datetime)). Is that even possible?

Comment: Add `ORDER BY count(DISTINCT DATE(usi.datetime)) DESC` at the end.